# Kibana setup on Ubuntu 17.10 for consuming log files from Jboss Fuse

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, jbossfuse

Every day I get a new log file from Jboss Fuse. Examples:

- fuse.log.2018-02-28
- fuse.log.2018-03-01
- fuse.log.2018-03-03

etc..

I want to load  a log file into Kibana every day.

Now this is what I have done so far:

- Installed Elasticsearch
- Installed ingest-geoip
- Installed Kibana on http://localhost:9200
- Installed Filebeat
- Installed logstash

What do I do from here? When I go to Kibana I only see the default dashboard screen "Add Data to Kibana":

[Kibana dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws3ak.png)

Thanks for any help.